# Python Stats Models api does not output AIC/BIC scores

Tags: python, statsmodels

I come from SAS/R universe and this is my first foray into building GLMs using Python. I noticed that the Stats models api does not give me AIC/BIC in summary statistics [enter link description here](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/glm.html)

Is there a way to get AiC and BIC scores from stats models ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I was looking at the model.summary() and was not getting what I needed. I had to look up individual values from the fitted model.

For a fitted model
`Loglikelihood = model.llf`
`AIC = model.aic`
`BIC = model.bic`

Use this [link](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLMResults.html) for additional metrics